# NgbDropdown custom arrow for dropup button

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to have different arrows for toggle drop-up button. 
how can we use different arrows? when its showing drop up menu, then it should have down arrow and  when it doesn't show any menu then it should have up arrow

```
 <div class="col text-right">
    <div ngbDropdown placement="top-right" class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic2" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropup</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic2">
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your current source code for this problem?

Comment: The standard behavior of bootstrap is to keep the same icon whether or not the popup is opened, and ng-bootstrap just has the same behavior. It's done by the bootstrap css.

Comment: Can we change it?  I need to design the drop-up button as per the requirement